# How does transpose and reshape exactly work?

Tags: python, arrays, image, numpy, image-processing

I was reshaping my image to feed into a CNN. Instead of using reshape function I used transpose to change the shape of the image. But when i tried to reshape the img to it's original shape this happend.

```
img = cv2.imread("test.jpg")
img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
plt.imshow(img)
```

[image]

```
imgT = img.transpose(2,0,1)
print(imgT.shape)
x = imgT.reshape(224,224,3)
plt.imshow(x)
```

[image]

I tried looking up different resources to know the difference between reshape and transpose like [this](https://lihan.me/2018/01/numpy-reshape-and-transpose/)

And I know that

```
imgT[:3,0,0] == img[0,0,:3]
```

and

```
imgT[:3,:,0].transpose() == img[:,0,:3]
```

But I am still not getting how the images are repeating itself.

Thanks

Comment: Transpose has moved the color dimension to the front.  Why do you use a reshape that assumes it is last?

Comment: I know what i did with the reshape is wrong. But I am not exactly getting why the resultant image is having multiple copies of the same image. That what i am trying to understand. Thanks

Comment: Is `img` a `numpy` array, or a `cv2` object?  The methods could be different.  Looks like the replicated images differ slightly, as though they are b/w renditions of different color ranges.

Comment: img is a numpy array of shape (224,224,3).

Answer (score 0):

The reason I questioned the type of `img` is because that sequence of operations, on numpy arrays, shouldn't produce anything recognizable.

To illustrate with a small array:

```
In [46]: arr = np.arange(16).reshape(4,4)
In [47]: img = arr[:,:,None] * np.arange(1,4)
In [48]: img.shape
Out[48]: (4, 4, 3)
In [51]: imgT = img.transpose(2,0,1)
In [52]: img.T
Out[52]: 
array([[[ 0,  4,  8, 12],
        [ 1,  5,  9, 13],
        [ 2,  6, 10, 14],
        [ 3,  7, 11, 15]],

       [[ 0,  8, 16, 24],
        [ 2, 10, 18, 26],
        [ 4, 12, 20, 28],
        [ 6, 14, 22, 30]],

       [[ 0, 12, 24, 36],
        [ 3, 15, 27, 39],
        [ 6, 18, 30, 42],
        [ 9, 21, 33, 45]]])
In [53]: x = imgT.reshape(4,4,3)
In [54]: img[:,:,0]
Out[54]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11],
       [12, 13, 14, 15]])
In [55]: x[:,:,0]
Out[55]: 
array([[ 0,  3,  6,  9],
       [12, 15,  4, 10],
       [16, 22, 28,  3],
       [12, 21, 30, 39]])
```

As you can see it's hard to trace a connection between `img` 'colors' and `x`.